# What will be order of execution if I am attaching two same event on a DOM

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I am attaching two click events on an element then what will be order of execution of the two handler. I know the order of execution for jQuery is the same as the order in which the events were attached. But I am not sure about the behaviour with JavaScript.

**If it just appends the events handler then if I want to override all existing events handler how can I do it?**

Comment: Are the handlers you need to override appended with jQuery?

Comment: yeah with jQuery but attaching with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The handlers will execute in the order in which they were bound](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc).

The [DOM3 event spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow), introduces the requirement that they be fired in order of registration (what most browsers do):

> Next, the implementation must determine the current target's candidate event listeners. This must be the list of all event listeners that have been registered on the current target in their order of registration.

From [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> Events in the target phase will trigger all listeners on an element in the order they were registered, regardless of the useCapture parameter.-

In addition:
 [Javascript event order](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4)

Comment: I also think the same but I was wondering about the source where I can verify this.

Comment: My answer is the link to the source :)

Comment: Your answer is a link to the jQuery docs about the deprecated `.bind()` method. The question is about the DOM API.

Comment: I have written in my question only that handlers are appended in jQuery. May be jQuery uses some logics to append it. I am asking about Core JS.

Comment: I agree with @PeterMader. What is the behaviour of DOM API :/

Comment: I updated answer. It is clearly declared in DOM3, trying to find about DOM4

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to remove or override the event handlers attached by jQuery with `.on()` method then you could use the `.off()` method respectively to remove them. Then add again the handler you do want to use. Check the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Let's say the handlers you know they are already attached are named functions like so:

```
function someHandler(e) {
  // do something with the event e
}

$('#myElement').on('click', someHandler);
```

You can remove this one by calling

```
$('#myElement').off('click', someHandler);
```

If the handlers though we anonymous functions like so:

```
$('#myElement').on('click', function(e) { ... } );
```

then you must remove all listeners attached **with jQuery** (jQuery keeps track of the events/listeners/handlers attached)

```
$('#myElement').off('click'); // remove ALL handlers for the event
```

Comment: But my first question is the behaviour of attaching multiple click event to an element.

Comment: Others correctly answered that event listeners and handlers are called in the order they got attached (jquery or vanilla javascript it doesn't matter, jquery uses native events under the hood). Your question IMO is actually two seperate questions. The first asking about the order of events and the other asking how to override an event handler.